# How to generate model using Ember-cli with attributes using options (include relationship)?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I remember there is a way to generate a model with all the attributes and relationship for a model using ember-cli something like below,

```
ember g model user name:string email:string user:has-many
```

So that I can avoid to type all `attr` again and again.

```
name: DS.attr('string')
```

But I could not find any reference about it. Where can I find more ref. about the detailed usage on how to generate a model with attritbues and relationships?

**Question**

Where can I find the detailed `option` reference for command `ember generate <generator-name> <options>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following help info. using

```
ember help generate model
```

Reference, https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/3316

```
Requested ember-cli commands:

ember generate <blueprint> <options...>
  Generates new code from blueprints.
  aliases: g
  --dry-run (Boolean) (Default: false)
    aliases: -d
  --verbose (Boolean) (Default: false)
    aliases: -v
  --pod (Boolean) (Default: false)
    aliases: -p
  --classic (Boolean) (Default: false)
    aliases: -c
  --dummy (Boolean) (Default: false)
    aliases: -dum, -id
  --in-repo-addon (String) (Default: null)
    aliases: --in-repo <value>, -ir <value>

      model <name> <attr:type>
        Generates an ember-data model.
        You may generate models with as many attrs as you would like to pass. The following attribute types are supported:
        <attr-name>
        <attr-name>:array
        <attr-name>:boolean
        <attr-name>:date
        <attr-name>:object
        <attr-name>:number
        <attr-name>:string
        <attr-name>:your-custom-transform
        <attr-name>:belongs-to:<model-name>
        <attr-name>:has-many:<model-name>

        For instance: `ember generate model taco filling:belongs-to:protein toppings:has-many:toppings name:string price:number misc`
        would result in the following model:


        import DS from 'ember-data';

        export default DS.Model.extend({
          filling: DS.belongsTo('protein'),
          toppings: DS.hasMany('topping'),
          name: DS.attr('string'),
          price: DS.attr('number'),
          misc: DS.attr()
        });
```